# Xamarin app null being returned from portable class library

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a portable class library for retrieving data from an api for an android app I am developing with Xamarin. I am only getting null values from any of the methods in the PCL, I am also not able to debug the Portable Class Library. I created a basic class with a method that returns an int to see if the problem was in my connection to the the api but it still returns null, i have been unable to figure out why this is happening (it is probably something extremely obvious). this is the code I have for returning the int.

```
namespace TradeOffAndroidApp.Core.DataService
{
    public class CategoryDataService
    {
        public int AInt()
        {
            return 111;
        }
    }
}
```

then in my activity I have

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using TradeOffAndroidApp.Core.DataService;
namespace TradeOffAndroidApp
{
    [Activity(Label = "CategoriesActivity")]
    public class CategoriesActivity : Activity
    {
        private CategoryDataService testClass;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            int a = 0;
            a = testClass.AInt();
        }
    }
}
```

The exception getting thrown on int a is

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object. occurred

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to create an instance of a class before you can access it

```
testClasss = new CategoryDataService();
int a = testClass.AInt();
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry for wasting your time on such an obvious question, I don't know how I didn't realize. I will mark as accepted after the required time